# LaTeX hyperref package: Opening a target PDF at a specific page

Tags: file, pdf, latex, hyperref

Does anyone know if it is possible to employ the LaTeX hyperref package to open a target PDf at a specific page?  I have tried using the \href{FILENAME#page=XX}{LINK_TEXT} command, where XX is the target page number, but no dice.  The file iteself opens, but it always starts out at the first page.  The idea being that I have a large index which is a separate document; each item in the index has a link to the target document along with the page number.

Perhaps I am using the wrong linking macro?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the documents are created using pdfLatex, you should be able to do what you want by:

```
\href{filename#page.xx}{link text}
```

Note the `.` instead of `=` after `page`.

Comment: That works wonders.  Is this documented anywhere in the hyperref package?

Comment: Doesn't work for me :-/  According to the manual, `\href[page:xx]{filename}{link text}` should work, but it doesn't either.

Comment: How does it work when then document is not created using pdfLatex?